# Using Django's RegexValidator outside of models

Tags: django, django-validation

I defined a regex validator using Django's built in library. I use it to validate my fields on my models. Like this:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

validate_alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=40, validators=[validate_alphanumeric])
```

However, how can I use it outside of my fields? Like lets say I want to validate the string `'Hello'` using the validator, provided the validator is stored in a regular variable, instead of a model. The docs seemed pretty confusing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite simply: a validator is a callable, so you just call it with the value to validate, and if the value doesn't validate it will raise a `ValidationError`:

```
>>> from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
>>> validate_alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')
>>> validate_alphanumeric("foo") # ok, nothing happens
>>> validate_alphanumeric("++") # raises a ValidationError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/bruno/.virtualenvs/blook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/validators.py", line 61, in __call__
    raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code)
ValidationError: [u'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.']
>>>
```

Comment: Ok this makes sense. How would you call some other built-in validator that does not need a definition? Like lets say the `MinValueValidator`?

Comment: `MinValueValidator` DOES require a definition - you have to set the min value ;) But anyway: all validators work the same way, and you can easily read the source code (to find out implementation details or things that would be missing from the doc) and try things out in your django shell.

Comment: What if I want to add code ?

Comment: @BipLob as mentionned at the very beginning of the answer, "a validator is a callable" (as defined here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=callable)